# Nodejs = Downloading file returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

When I click the URL directly in a web browser, the proper csv file downloads. If I download the file with nodejs, the file downloads, but it contains html code inside of it instead of the data I need.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("history/a.csv");
var request = http.get("http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=AAL&startdate=Feb+28+2017&output=csv", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

The file produced: `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1    minimum-scale=1     width=device-width"><title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title><style>*{margin:0;padding:0}html    code{font:15px/22px arial   sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{color:#222;text-align:unset;margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px;}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}pre{white-space:pre-wrap;}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}</style><div id="af-error-container"><a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a><p><b>404.</b> <ins>Thatâ€™s an error.</ins><p>The requested URL was not found on this server. <ins>Thatâ€™s all we know.</ins></div>`

Comment: Read the HTML, it will likely tell you something like that you need to login or the like.

Comment: @Paul I took a look at it and it is mostly just styling, no other information. There is no logging in because I can access it directly in the browser

Comment: Will you please add the html output what you get as your response?

Comment: Looks like a 404, then.

Comment: @Kanagu it says the URL was not found, but if I type that URL into a browser it exists.

Comment: I just testet the above code here and it works! I am getting the same result as in the browser (CSV).

Comment: @SebastianHildebrandt really? How can that be? The code I gave is exactly what I have in my index.js file. Nothing more, nothing less. Can I ask you if you have time to open the javascript file in notepad and click the encoding menu and see what encoding your file uses?

Comment: I agree, the URL works fine in Node as well.  Are you behind a corporate proxy or something?

Comment: @Paul No this is my home computer.

Comment: Can I ask what IDE you guys are using?

Comment: I just ran it from the node REPL.

Comment: hmmmm why is this happening?

Comment: I tired running from administrator, but no luck.

Comment: Hard to say without being able to repeat your experience.  I'd say you should look at the version of Node you're running, upgrade if you can, and see if there's not something wrong with the network making it intermittently fail.

Comment: Worth noting, I'm running this on Mac. Might be a Windows problem if you're on Windows.

Comment: @Paul just tried running it on my linux box, but the same problem occurs. I don't think it is a network issue because from the browser directly it does work. There is nothing blocking this.

Comment: @Paul If I change the stock from AAL to GOOG or any other thing it works. It seems to only be AAL. Again from the browser it works. Is AAL something special? Some encoding issue?

Comment: I think it is the problem of CORS, Please check with other url which supports cors. When it is browser it will not violate CORS policy. see the console in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zrxgcqb/4/). I have changed the url to a local url (which is running in another port by wamp) and your code downloads the csv file fine

Comment: @Kanagu that doesn't make sense, since others of us have successfully made the request via Node REPL (not a browser).  Also, it's pretty unlikely that CORS would be enabled for one querystring value on a resource but not another.

Comment: I agree. I do not think, this is a CORS problem. This COULD happen within a browser, because browsers by default block this (unless you explicitly allow it from server side). On the node side, this should not be a problem. Especially because I am sometimes using node as a proxy to avoid CORS on client side ;-) ... but this is another story. I just tested it on another machine. Result is fine (like in the browser) ï»¿Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
29-May-17,-,-,-,41.90,0
26-May-17,-,-,-,41.90,0
24-May-17,41.90,41.90,41.90,41.90,0
23-May-17,41.29,41.29,41.29,41.29,0